# How to program over an Arabic text; counting number of each letter, e.g

Tags: javascript, unicode, arabic, counting

How to get JavaScript to recognize Arabic, to count the occurrences of each letter written in the actual Unicode letters (non-English).

I tried copying and pasting Arabic to see if JavaScript would recognize it as an implementation of Unicode. That didn't work.

```
// this works
var Omega = '\u03A9';
console.log(Omega);

//this doesn't
var script = 'ذَلِكَ ٱلْكِتَبُ لَا رَيْبَ ۛ فِيهِ ۛ هُدًۭى لِّلْمُتَّقِينَ';
console.log(script);
```

The actual result of the script variable should log to the console exactly what's showing. How can I program over actual Arabic letters and reference these letters later for counting purposes using Unicode?

Comment: Works for me. The issue is likely with your console configuration

Comment: I don't know Arabic, but is [this](https://i.imgur.com/wWkqIeX.png) the right output? Don't forget the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your HTML.

Comment: the meta tag worked. thanks to you both.